# PHP: Output single array as multiple lists

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array of unknown length:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' ...);
```

I need to output this array as multiple lists, where a new list is created for every 3 array entries.

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Note that I need to close the last list even if it does not contain 3 list-items.

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); ++$i): ?>

  <?php if (($i % 3) == 0): ?>
    <ul>
  <?php endif; ?>
    <li><?php print $rows[$i]; ?></li>
  <?php if (($i % 3) == 2): ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: *I have tried* show us your attempt

Comment: I think now you got various answers and all are very interesting, go trough each answer and choose one which works for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could utilize an `array_chunk` for this task. Chunk them by threes:

```
$array = range(1, 8);
$unknown_length = array_chunk($array, 3); // cut by batches of three
foreach($unknown_length as $ul) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($ul as $li) {
        echo "<li>$li</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NjjbeX)

Comment: `array_chunk` and very meaningful variable names that's a good example of code

Comment: @Rizier123 i didn't thought about it actually, just first thing that popped out of my head while typing. lol :D.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

(Here I split the array in chunks of 3 with [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). Then I loop through each innerArray with a foreach loop and print the lists with [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php))

```
<?php

    $array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8');

    foreach(array_chunk($array, 3) as $chunk) 
        echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>', $chunk) . "</li></ul>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with foreach loop

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8');
$i=1;
foreach($array as $a) {
  if($i == 1) echo '<ul>';
  echo '<li>'.$a.'</li>';
  if($i % 3 == 0) {
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<ul>';
  }
  if($i == count($array))
    echo '</ul>';
  $i++;
}
```

output :-

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $value){
   switch($i){
      case 1:
         echo '<ul>' 
               . '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
         break;
      case 2:
         echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
         break;
      case 3:
         echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'
              . '</ul>';
         $i = 0;
         break;
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Okay one thing i have to admit here. You wrote the only answer i never would have thought of and i didn't expected it, but it's a very creative solution.

Comment: Thanks! It's not very advanced or structural complex, but it works and is simple to understand. @Rizier123

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8');
echo "<ul>";
foreach($array as $key => $val){

    echo "<li>$val</li>";

    if(($key+1)%3 == 0){
        echo "</ul><ul>";       
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KKk4Mz)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8');

        $n = count($array);
        $i=1;
        $list = '';
        foreach ($array as $val) {

            if($i==1){
                $list .='<ul>';
            }
                $list .='<li>'.$val.'</li>';
            if($i%3==0){
                $list .='</ul>';
                $list .='<ul>';
            }

            if($n==$i){ $list .='</ul>'; }
            $i++;
        }
        echo $list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use template-like alternative loop syntax right in HTML? (of course if you are using some kind of "views")

```
<? for ($i=0; $i<count($a); $i+=3): ?>
    <ul>
    <? for ($j=$i; $j<min(count($a), $i+3); $j++): ?>
        <li><? echo $a[$j]; ?></li>
    <? endfor; ?>
    </ul>
<? endfor; ?>
```